# Changing CGRectMake (x,x,x,x) to a different location such as (y,y,y,y)

Tags: ios, user-interface, orientation, rotation, cgrect

I have placed a button in my view using CGRectMake(x,x,x,x), x being the location and size of course. When I rotate the view using -(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate... I want to change the location of the button from what would be the center in portrait mode to the center in landscape mode. The button contains information in its label that the user sets, so I DON'T want to use a different view for the landscape orientation. What if they set something in portrait and rotate to horizontal? They'll lose their data. So my question is: how do I move something that was previously set? See the code below, I don't want to realloc the button. Thanks!

```
// DATE

lblDate = [[UILabel  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];

lblDate.text = @"Date:";
lblDate.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[contentView addSubview:lblDate];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just set the frame equal to a new Rect, e.g.

```
lblDate.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,width,height);
```

Answer (score 0):

lblDate.frame = newRect

But you should probably be using autoresizing flags for this.

Answer (score 0):

As found in the [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds).

> ***frame***
>
> The frame rectangle, which describes
>   the view’s location and size in its
>   superview’s coordinate system.
>
> @property(nonatomic) CGRect frame
>   Discussion This rectangle defines the
>   size and position of the view in its
>   superview’s coordinate system. You use
>   this rectangle during layout
>   operations to size and position the
>   view. Setting this property changes
>   the point specified by the center
>   property and the size in the bounds
>   rectangle accordingly. The coordinates
>   of the frame rectangle are always
>   specified in points.
>
> Warning: If the transform property is
>   not the identity transform, the value
>   of this property is undefined and
>   therefore should be ignored.
>
> Changing the frame rectangle
>   automatically redisplays the receiver
>   without invoking the drawRect: method.
>   If you want the drawRect: method
>   invoked when the frame rectangle
>   changes, set the contentMode property
>   to UIViewContentModeRedraw.
>
> Changes to this property can be
>   animated. However, if the transform
>   property contains a non-identity
>   transform, the value of the frame
>   property is undefined and should not
>   be modified. In that case, you can
>   reposition the view using the center
>   property and adjust the size using the
>   bounds property instead.